# Post request from iPhone using ASIFormDataRequest not working

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post, asihttprequest

Newbie to Rails/iOS here. I have a rails blog application. I'm trying to upload a post from iOS using an HTTP POST method with [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest). Here's the code that get's called:

```
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"name"];

    [request setFile:@"star.png" forKey:@"image"]; 
    [request startSynchronous];  
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"response:: %@", response);
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. My server does not get contacted. I get response:: (null).  Any idea why?

**EDIT** I found out that star.png needed to have its full file address. Now the POST works fine, but neither the name or image get saved into the db. A new post with empty name and image gets created. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the response of the request?

Comment: Do you threat the error for request?

Comment: The problem was that I had to put the entire file address for star.png. Now the server receives the POST, but it doesn't get written into the databse for some reason.

Comment: So the problem is on the server side not on the iPhone app.

Comment: the server side is fine. upload works fine from a browser. there's something wrong with the way i'm making the request on iphone.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using localhost here?

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"];
```

use your web server ip instead of localhost

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://yourservername:3000/posts"];
```

Comment: can you tell me? what is your rails server ip and iphone ip? I want you to put web-server ip there like: http://webserverip:3000/posts

Comment: one thing you can check :), what you will get if you put http://localhost:3000 on you iPhone safari?

Comment: I get my rails app at localhost:3000. THe iphone is connecting to the server now. i just need it to save to db. That's the part that's not working. I've updated the question.

Comment: how you tell me that you iPhone is connecting to you localhost:3000 ? did you try to put that http address on your iphone safari and be confirm?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"name"];

[request setPostValue:imageData forKey:@"image"]; 
[request startSynchronous];
```

For the "imagePath" is the path to your image. The full path.

Comment: I fixed that part. Now it won't get saved into the db. Here's a log from a successful post from a browser:Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Post", "post"=>{"name"=>"119am", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x104038d10 @content_type="image/png", @original_filename="Screen shot 2011-05-01 at 11.21.28 PM.png",...    and here's one from when i post from iphone:  Parameters: {"name"=>"Ben", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x103efd4a0 @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="beach.jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";...